# PyArrow: How to copy files from local to remote using new filesystem interface?

Tags: python, hdfs, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Could somebody give me a hint on how can I copy a file form a local filesystem to a HDFS filesystem using [PyArrow's new filesystem interface](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html) (i.e. upload, copyFromLocal)?

I have read the documentation back-and-forth, and tried a few things out (using copy_file() with FS URIs), but none of it seems to work. The usage of the [legacy HDFS API](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems_deprecated.html) is straightforward, but it is deprecated, though the new API seems to be incomplete. Of course moving chunks of data among file descriptors is a solutions, but why [copy_file()](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.copy_file) exists then?

Answer (score 6):

There are no functions in the new (or old) filesystem APIs for transferring files between filesystems.

> Of course moving chunks of data among file descriptors is a solutions

I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking, but here is a simple utility (and demo) on how to do this from python:

```
import filecmp
import pyarrow.fs as pafs

BATCH_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

def transfer_file(in_fs, in_path, out_fs, out_path):
    with in_fs.open_input_stream(in_path) as in_file:
        with out_fs.open_output_stream(out_path) as out_file:
            while True:
                buf = in_file.read(BATCH_SIZE)
                if buf:
                    out_file.write(buf)
                else:
                    break

local_fs = pafs.LocalFileSystem()
s3fs = pafs.S3FileSystem()
in_path = '/tmp/in.data'
out_path = 'mybucket/test.data'
back_out_path = '/tmp/in_copy.data'

transfer_file(local_fs, in_path, s3fs, out_path)
transfer_file(s3fs, out_path, local_fs, back_out_path)

files_match = filecmp.cmp(in_path, back_out_path)
print(f'Files Match: {files_match}')
```

I would expect `transfer_file` to get good performance.  There may be some situations (e.g. reading from S3) that could benefit from a parallel read using `read_at` which would require a bit more complexity but should also be doable.

> but why copy_file() exists then?

`copy_file` copies a file from one name on a filesystem to a different name *on the same filesystem*.  It cannot be used to copy files between different filesystems.

Comment: Makes sense! I'll wait a few days for more answers, but your thoughts are confirming my assumptions. Thank you!

Comment: This definitely solved my problem. Thank you Pace!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Pace's answer (too long for a comment):  I was copying gzip files (*.gz) which pyarrow was (by default) decompressing with each `read()` call and then compressing again with each `write()` call.  I verified this with the print statement shown below in Pace's version of the code.

So, to get *significantly* faster transfers/copies, turn off compression:

```
def transfer_file(in_fs, in_path, out_fs, out_path):
    with in_fs.open_input_stream(in_path, compression=None) as in_file:
        with out_fs.open_output_stream(out_path, compression=None) as out_file:
            while True:
                buf = in_file.read(BATCH_SIZE)
                if buf:
                    print(f'buf size: len(buf)')
                    out_file.write(buf)
                else:
                    break
```